# OLEDB table fetching function in C#

Tags: c#, linq, database

I'm working on a small project with dBase files from a 3rd party. Realizing that most of the code to fetch tables and form objects is the same, I made this function:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OleDbFetch<T>(Func<OleDbDataReader, T> formator, string connectionString, string query)
{
    var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
        yield return formator(reader);
    conn.Close();
}
```

That way I can use it with all sorts of classes (pre-made, imposed) that have mostly parameter-less constructors:

```
class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person() { }
}

//...

var persons = OleDbFetch<Person>(
    r => new Person()
    { 
        ID = Convert.ToInt32(r["ID"]), 
        Name = r["Name"].ToString() 
    }, 
    connString, "SELECT ID, Name FROM Person");
```

Am I missing something obvious, being reckless, or giving myself too much trouble?

Comment: I guess I should secure the connection... Make sure it's open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Dispose()` of types that implement `IDisposable` with `using` blocks:

```
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            yield return formator(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a sucker for explicitly closing connections...